# Error al registrar usuario a mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al registrar un usuario, me sale lo siguiente, me pdorian ayudar a encontrar el error. POR FAVOR!

ESTA ES LA CONEXION

Y ESTE ES PARA INGRESAR LOS DATOS.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['apellido1']=$_POST['apellido1'];
    $_SESSION['apellido2']=$_POST['apellido2'];
    $_SESSION['cell']=$_POST['cell'];
    //Consulta en Mysql
    $linea1="INSERT INTO alumno (
    nombres,
    apellido_pa,
    apellido_ma,
    celular
    ) ";
    $linea2=" VALUES ('',
    '".$_SESSION['nombre']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['apellido1']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['apellido2']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['cell']."') ";
    $consulta=$linea1.$linea2;
    //echo "$consulta";
    include_once("conexion.php");
    conexion($consulta);
    echo "<br>Alumno Registrado";
    echo "<br><br><a href='../index.html'>Inicio</a>";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas agregando un campo vació de mas al inicio, ya que solo tienes definido 4 campos a insertar. quita esa cadena vacía y prueba.

Ejemplo:

```
$linea1="INSERT INTO alumno (
    nombres,
    apellido_pa,
    apellido_ma,
    celular
    ) ";
$linea2=" VALUES (
    '".$_SESSION['nombre']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['apellido1']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['apellido2']."', 
    '".$_SESSION['cell']."') "; 
$consulta=$linea1.$linea2;
```